# django-redis connection error inside docker

Tags: django, redis

django views.py

```
import redis
import jwt
from access import utils
import os
redis_url = os.environ['REDIS_URI']

R = redis.StrictRedis(redis_url)

def set(request):
    R.set('foo', 'bar')
    return JsonResponse({"code":200,"msg":"success"})
```

docker-compose

```
version: "3"

services:
  rango:
    container_name: rango
    build: ./
    command: python backend/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    # command: npm start --prefix frontend/rango-frontend/
    working_dir: /usr/src/rango
    environment:
      REDIS_URI: redis://redis_db:6379
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    tty: true
    links:
      - elasticsearch
      - node
      - redis

  #elastic search
  elasticsearch:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:6.5.0
    ports:
      - "9200:9200"

  #node
  node:
    image: node:10.13.0

  #redis
  redis:
    image: redis
    environment:
      - ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=yes
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
```

here i am connecting redis from django inside docker. 
it is giving me exceptions connexctions refused.
Please have a look into my code and shared screenshot below

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. In addition to posting the code, please be sure to ask a clear question. [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Thanks.

Comment: Could you show your Redis configuration in settings.py?

Comment: i am not using redis with client. not in settinggs.py

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, docker compose makes containers discoverable with a hostname identical to the container name. Your redis container is thus discoverable via the hostname `redis`. However, your Django container is using the hostname `redis_db`.

Update your `docker-compose.yml` and change the `REDIS_URI` to reference the correct hostname:

```
REDIS_URI: redis://redis:6379
```

Comment: in python what changes i need to do.

Comment: No changes in python. You just need to update your `docker-compose.yml` and change the `REDIS_URI` to `redis://redis:6379`

Comment: and do i nee to start redis inside the docker or it will automatically start. just like in local system we need to start redis server before working on it using src/redis-server

Comment: Redis will come up when the container starts. You don't need to enter the container to start it.

Comment: rango        | redis.exceptions.ConnectionError: Error -2 connecting to redis://redis:6379:6379. Name or service not known.


    showing error

Comment: "ExposedPorts": {
                "6379/tcp": {}
            },

Comment: If you're trying to access the redis container from the host machine, you'll need to use `localhost` for the hostname. You should only use the hostname `redis` when accessing redis from another container - i.e. `rango` in your case.

Comment: no i am not accessing redis from my local machine . both python-django and redis are inside docker. in console it is showing

redis_1_2e356017fd0f | 1:M 19 Nov 2018 14:26:29.554 * Ready to accept connections


i think the issue in python side while connect into redis

Comment: hi, i have exact same issue. did you figure it out? mind sharing?