# redis connection error within docker container

Tags: python-3.x, flask, redis, docker-compose

I'm trying to setup a light-weight RQ task queue app running in Docker. I keep on getting this error:

`ValueError: Redis URL must specify one of the following schemes (redis://, rediss://, unix://)`

When grabbing from environmental variable (`os.getenv()`) it doesn't work, but somehow when hard-coding in `redis://redis:6379/0`, it seems to work. However, this is not really a long-term solution in my opinion. I looked at: [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53359634/django-redis-connection-error-inside-docker) and [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60216161/docker-compose-redis-container-refusing-connection-to-node-container), but there wasn't really a solution, the thread went dead.

My redis connection code is like so:

```
import os
import redis
from rq import Worker, Queue, Connection

listen = ['default']
redis_url = os.getenv('REDIS_URL', 'redis://localhost:6379')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(f"redis url: {redis_url}")
    with Connection(redis.from_url(redis_url)):
        worker = Worker(list(map(Queue, listen)))
        worker.work()
```

When it prints the `redis_url` it is correct; I set the environmental var, `REDIS_URL` to `redis://redis:6379` where redis is the hostname in docker-compose.yml.

```
  redis:
    image: redis:alpine
    expose:
      - '6379'
```

Appreciate any help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Found out it there were mysterious `\` at the ends of the string, so I used `.strip()` and it works using the `.getenv()` method. I think it has something to do with how docker-compose passes the variable to flask; my best guess.