# Heroku Django Celerey: raised unexpected: ValueError Server 500 error

Tags: python, django, heroku, redis, django-celery

I am trying to schedule some tasks one Django celery on my Heroku application however, I have got an error:

```
raised unexpected: ValueError('Redis URL must specify one of the following schemes (redis://, rediss://, unix://)',)
```

Now for your reference, I have three settings files for my production and development environment with a common one. My app is called register and the file containing the `wsgi.py` is:

```
register
    -settings
    ----common.py
    ----production.py
    ----development.py
    -celery.py
    -wsgi.py
```

Now in my `production.py` file I have:

```
from register.settings.common import *
import os
from urllib.parse import urlparse
import django_heroku


DEBUG = False

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['mysite.herokuapp.com','wwww.mysite.com','mysite.com']

#EMAIL_HOST_USER = os.environ.get('EMAIL_HOST_USER')
#EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = os.environ.get('EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD')

redis_url = urlparse(os.environ.get('REDISTOGO_URL', 'redis://localhost:6959'))

CACHES = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': "django_redis.cache.RedisCache",
        'LOCATION': '%s:%s' % (redis_url.hostname, redis_url.port),
        'OPTIONS': {
            'DB': 0,
            'PASSWORD': redis_url.password,
        }
    }
}

CELERY_BROKER_URL=os.environ.get('REDISTOGO_URL')
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND=os.environ.get('REDISTOGO_URL')
CELERY_BROKER_TRANSPORT_OPTIONS = {
    "max_connections": 2,
}
db_from_env = dj_database_url.config(conn_max_age=600)
    DATABASES['default'].update(db_from_env)
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage'
    
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
    django_heroku.settings(locals(),logging=False)
```

And in my `celery.py` file I have:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
import os
from celery import Celery
from django.conf import settings
import django

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'register.settings.production')

app = Celery('register')

app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')
app.autodiscover_tasks(lambda: settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
```

I do not know what is causing this error as when I do `heroku config` I can see that the config vars are set correctly.

This is also my procfile:

```
web: gunicorn register.wsgi:application --env DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE='register.settings.production' --log-file -
worker: celery -A register worker -E -l info
celery_beat: celery -A register beat --loglevel=info
```

**EDIT**

After my worker error: I also see this error:

```
2020-09-07T16:19:37.558111+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=mysite.com request_id=4ce6cc94-2ae3-4da8-90fc-c341c4c24a31 fwd="99.255.202.184" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=27ms status=500 bytes=380 protocol=http
```

I do not know if they are related to each other or not. Or is it because of my URL configurations

Comment: Did you have a look at [this related question?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63269031/redis-connection-error-within-docker-container)

Comment: Thanks but after following the link it did not solve my issue @el_bobo